# How to assign GROUP to user from a registration form (for user) in Django?

Tags: python, django

The problem that I face, is that I do not know how to assign a group to a user directly from a formal registration of a template (application) in Django. My user registration view is this:

```
def UserRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register/user_register.html', {'form': form})
```

- POSTDATA: to assign roles, I use django-role-permissions. I do not want to register a group, I just want to include it with the user who registers without having to do in the Django panel.

Answer (score 15):

Typically you would pull in the group model from django. Then query the model for the group you would like to add the user. Here is how to below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def UserRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='group_name')
            user.groups.add(group)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register/user_register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I have a problem. This is the error: "<User: 1014>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used. I use the default user model of Django.

Comment: Seems we need to do the .save() before adding the group. Should be able to remove the commit=False and the .save()

Comment: For me it worked, but I used different signup view.

Comment: I tried what @MitchellWalls said, by adding `user.save()` before `user.groups.add(group)`, and it solved my problem.

Comment: I tried what @MitchellWalls said while saving a form and worked, by adding form.save() before form.groups.add(group)